# Execution Context has been Destroyed Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

"Most likely due to page navigation"

The page I'm trying to use has the following behavior. To get to the content I want, I have to click a button. But on clicking that button, the content I want is loaded on a new tab. The current tab I'm on navigates to a useless ad. When I try to do anything with "page" (page.eval, page.url()), it gives me the above error (the actual browser gives an error about the page having been moved permanently).

How do I get puppeteer to follow the new tab instead of getting stuck on the old one?

I've tried making a separate third tab with puppeteer newPage and goto, which works, kind of, but that runs into other issues down the road. I'm looking for a different way.

Edit:

I followed the answer below and did this:

```
    const [newPage, oldPage] = await Promise.all([getNewPage(), getOldPage()]);

    console.log("new page", newPage.url());
    console.log("old page", oldPage.url());

    function getOldPage() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        page.evaluate(function () {
          let element = document.querySelector("button[class*=OfferCta__]");
          element.click();
        });
        resolve(page);
      });
    }
    function getNewPage() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        browser.on("targetcreated", checkNewTarget);

        function checkNewTarget(target) {
          if (target.type() === "page") {
            browser.off("targetcreated", checkNewTarget);
            resolve(target.page());
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

It didn't work. I got this console:

```
3:17:40 PM web.1 |  new page https://www.nike.com/register?cid=4942550&cp=usns_aff_nike__PID_2210202_WhaleShark+Media%3A+RetailMeNot.com&cjevent=3a020cab18a211eb830d00030a1c0e0c
3:17:40 PM web.1 |  old page chrome-error://chromewebdata/
```

So by the time the Promise checks on the old url that I need, it is already erroring out.

EDIT:
It turns out I was blocking navigation requests when I was trying to block third-party scripts. This caused my button press to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
  const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
    getNewPage(),
    page.click(selector),
  ]);

  // ...

  function getNewPage() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      browser.on('targetcreated', checkNewTarget);

      function checkNewTarget(target) {
        if (target.type() === 'page') {
          browser.off('targetcreated', checkNewTarget);
          resolve(target.page());
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this with other case and it happens that sometimes other types of targets are created before a new page (with type 'other' for example), so this is a safety check.